# python tkinter entry input divided by label input from optionMenu

Tags: python, math, tkinter

I need a bit off help..
In the example below I have two optionsMenus, two entries, and some labels.

What I'm trying to do, is to divide my input from the entry by the labels value, choosen from the optionsMenu, and then show the new value in the next column. But I'm a bit stuck now and can't get it to work.

```
from tkinter import *

class App(Frame):
    def __init__(self, root=None):
        Frame.__init__(self, root)

        self.materialPrice = {'Brick': 70, 'Rockwool': 50, 'Concrete': 20}

        materialvariable1 = StringVar(self, root)
        materialvariable1.set("Choose material")
        materialvariable2 = StringVar(self, root)
        materialvariable2.set("Choose materiale")

        self.w1 = OptionMenu(root, materialvariable1, *self.materialPrice, command=self.displayPrice).grid(row=2,
                                                                                                           column=0,
                                                                                                           columnspan=1,
                                                                                                           sticky='WE')
        self.w2 = OptionMenu(root, materialvariable2, *self.materialPrice, command=self.displayPrice2).grid(row=3,
                                                                                                            column=0,
                                                                                                            columnspan=1,
                                                                                                            sticky='WE')

        self.var = IntVar()
        self.var.set(float(0.00))
        self.var2 = IntVar()
        self.var2.set(float(0.00))

        self.entry1 = Entry(root, textvariable=self.var).grid(row=2, column=1)
        self.entry2 = Entry(root, textvariable=self.var2).grid(row=3, column=1)

        self.priceVarLabel1 = IntVar()
        self.priceVarLabel1.set(float(0.00))

        self.priceVarLabel2 = IntVar()
        self.priceVarLabel2.set(float(0.00))

        self.priceVarValue1 = Label(root, textvariable=self.priceVarLabel1, relief='sunken').grid(row=2,
                                                                                                  column=2,
                                                                                                  columnspan=1,
                                                                                                  sticky='WE')
        self.priceVarValue2 = Label(root, textvariable=self.priceVarLabel2, relief='sunken').grid(row=3,
                                                                                                  column=2,
                                                                                                  columnspan=1,
                                                                                                  sticky='WE')

        self.label1 = Label(root, textvariable=self.displayResult).grid(row=2, column=3)
        self.label2 = Label(root, textvariable=self.displayResult2).grid(row=3, column=3)

    def displayPrice(self, value):
        self.priceVarLabel1.set(self.materialPrice[value])

    def displayPrice2(self, value):
        self.priceVarLabel2.set(self.materialPrice[value])

    def displayResult(self):
        self.label1.set(self.entry1 / self.priceVarValue1)

    def displayResult2(self):
        self.label1.set(self.entry1 / self.priceVarValue1)


root = Tk()
app = App(root)
root.title("help")
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: What does "can't get it to work" mean? Does it compute the wrong values? Does it crash? Does it throw an error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add the division to your function:

```
def displayPrice(self, value):
    self.priceVarLabel1.set(self.materialPrice[value] / self.var.get())
```

You may want to change the starting value to 1 so that you don't get a ZeroDivisionError right off the bat.

BTW, initializing a widget and laying it out on the same line is a well known bug source. Always use 2 lines.

```
# very bad:
self.entry1 = Entry(root, textvariable=self.var).grid(row=2, column=1)

# good:
self.entry1 = Entry(root, textvariable=self.var)
self.entry1.grid(row=2, column=1)
```

Comment: Thanks for your input, I really appreciate it! now it works, like I want! But what if, I want to divide a 0.200 in my entry with the value in the label? All I get is 0.0 as a result.

Comment: @Math then you need `DoubleVar`, not `IntVar` ("double" is another name for "float").